# SCP from remote Linux system to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, remote, scp

I'm on ssh accessing my user account at school. I'm trying to download a particular file from my linux account to my current windows file system that Im on right now. Can i use scp? If yes Id really appreciate if you could give an example of how to download a file from a remote server to  windows

Answer (score 7):

WinSCP has windows binding for the scp protocol. I haven't used it in a long time, but I recall it being easy to use.

http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Comment: This. In 2019, WinScp is still absurdly fast and easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

You won't find scp or ssh natively on Windows. But you can always download [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) and [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), respectively if you find yourself in need of some *nix goodness on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `scp` installed on your Windows machine, you can use:

```
scp username@remotehost:~/path/to/remote/file ~/path/to/local/file
```

If you don't have scp installed, you can use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to install SCP for Windows.

Comment: On Windows, git comes with bash: you can use Git Bash to scp data from remote machines

Answer (score 0):

Install cygwin.  It has an ssh and scp client.  You'll have to initiate the copy from windows, but it'll work.

Alternatively, it might be possible to install an ssh daemon with cygwin, but I've never explored that.

Answer (score 0):

Install [PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) on your Windows machine by placing it inside your Windows folder (where notepad.exe is located), open the Windows Command line (**cmd**) and enter:

```
pscp urlToYourRemoteLinuxMachine:pathToYourFile pathToLocalWindowsMachineFile
```